# Ionic 2, Cannot set property style of #<HTMLElement>

Tags: angular, ionic2

Please help me, I don't know why when i start my ionic project I got below trouble, but with same source code, it's running well on other PC.

code JS:

```
import {Page, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
    import {ListFoodPage} from '../list-food/list-food';
    import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Page({
      templateUrl: 'build/pages/list-menu/list-menu.html'
    })
    export class MenuPage {
      static get parameters() {
        return [[NavController], [NavParams],[Http]];
      }

      constructor(nav, navParams,http) {
        this.nav = nav;
        this.http = http;
        this.menu = null;
        this.title = 'Menu';
        this.selectedItem = navParams.get('item');
        if(this.selectedItem){
          this.title = this.selectedItem.mn_nm;
          this.menu = this.selectedItem.sub_mn;
        }else{
          this.http.get('/data/menu?res_id=' + 'FIRST_RES').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
              this.menu = data.data;
          });
        }
      }

      itemTapped(event, item) {
        if(item.sub_mn === undefined || item.sub_mn.length == 0){
          this.nav.push(ListFoodPage, {
           item: item
         });
        }else{
         this.nav.push(MenuPage, {
           item: item
         });
       }
      }
    }
```

code html:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-title>{{title}}</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list class="menu">
    <button ion-item *ngFor="#menuitem of menu" (click)="itemTapped($event, menuitem)" style="background-image: url('{{menuitem.bg_img}}')">
      <h2>{{menuitem.mn_nm}}</h2>
      <P>
        {{menuitem.mn_dsc}}
      </P>
    </button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Browser error:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot set property style of #<HTMLElement> which has only a getter in [background-image: url('{{menuitem.bg_img}}') in MenuPage@9:87]
```

[My result when run on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swjVc.png)

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/DOM-attributes-now-on-the-prototype-chain) (as a reason to why it works on some machines but doesn't on others).

Anyway, you should use the designated [`ngStyle`](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/common/NgStyle-directive.html) directive.

You can do it ugly and directly in the template:

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="#menuitem of menu" (click)="itemTapped($event, menuitem)" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + menuitem.bg_img + ')'}">
```

Or a little nicer by adding a function to your `MenuPage` code:

```
generateUrlString(image) {
  return `url('${image}')`;
}
```

and

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="#menuitem of menu" (click)="itemTapped($event, menuitem)" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': generateUrlString(menuitem.bg_img)}">
```